# C# ANTLR grammar?

Tags: c#, antlr

I'm looking for turn-key [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) grammar for C# that generates a usable Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and is either back-end language agnostic or targets C#, C, C++ or D.

It doesn't need to support error reporting.

P.S. I'm not willing to do hardly any fix-up as the alternative is not very hard.

Comment: Hi,
Were you able to get a grammar for C#. If yes, could you please share it?

Comment: I never found one that was easy enough.

Comment: What is the "not hard alternative" you are contemplating?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: Gobs of regex that I'd already gotten mostly working.

Comment: And you can parse C# and build ASTs with a set of regexps?

Comment: No, but with only a little effort on the c# side I can do most of the translations I need one line at a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be waaaay too late, but you can get a [C# 4 grammar](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [C# grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1151612545460/CSharpParser.g) link, as well as an overview of [C# and ANTLR](http://www.manuelabadia.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,ff1dc504-f854-40b4-bfe7-250ce91efad7.aspx).  There are others for the other languages you mentioned [here](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list).

Comment: That's only for C# 1.0. C# 2.0 requires a substantially stronger parser to handle generics, but ANTLR should be able to handle it. Good luck with C# 3.0 and LINQ!  :)

Comment: Um, doesn't the C# and ANTLR overview only cover the C# ANTLR runtime? As in the OP requested a way to parse C# code using ANTLR - but this link provides a guide to using the C# code, generated by ANTLR, to parse a potentially arbitrary language?

Answer (score 3):

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) provides a full, validated grammar for C# 1.2, 2.0 and 3.0 with generics and LINQ expressions.

It automatically builds ASTs, allows you programmatic access to the ASTs for analysis or tranformation, or you can apply source-to-source transformations that also directly manipulate the tree.  The resulting AST can be prettyprinted back to source code, even retaining indentation and comments.

DMS also has mature front ends for other languages such as Java, PHP5, JavaScript, COBOL, C and C++.

EDIT: 1/31/2010:  The DMS C# parser has been extended to handle full C# 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can find C# 6 ANTLR grammar at official [grammars repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp).